# incorrect result returned from pg_database_size

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, zend-framework, pgadmin-4

I am using Zend MVC framework and Postgres. I want to find out the database size (including indexes). This is my query.

```
SELECT pg_database_size(current_database());
```

When I run this query in pgAdmin it returns me the value "9255879"

The same query when I run it in my application returns me a different value "78150791"

```
    public function getDbSize()
  {
    $sql          = "SELECT pg_database_size(current_database());";
    $dbSize = Custom_Db::query($sql)->fetchColumn(); // Custom_Db is a library to execute sql
    return $dbSize; // 78150791
  }
```

Why are the value inconsistent when I run the same query in pgadmin vs when I retrieve it via the application?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The most obvious explanation is that are you connected to different databases, and they have different sizes.

Comment: @jjanes thank you. seemed like the current_database() was picking up another db in the cluster.